# How can I know Battery is present or absent via script?

Tags: scripts

I want to know which command should I use in my script to check the Battery if it's present or absent. like an `if condition`. thanks

When I try with following command I get error.

```
test@test-pc:~$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/*
cat: /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/*: No such file or directory

test@test-pc:~$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status: No such file or directory
```

Also `acpi` is already installed.

I used  `dmesg | grep battery` to check the battery and the result was this:

```
[    1.309638] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    1.309643] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
```

The result of `acpi -i` is as following too:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 79%
Battery 0: design capacity 8244 mAh, last full capacity 6591 mAh = 79%
```

And now how can I use this result in my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status` may help you.

If the battery is present it's for example:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
Charging
```

Another place could be:

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/*
```

Or to view ACPI related information use the command:

```
acpi -i
```

`acpi -i` produces no output to the standard output when no battery is present. In a script use it as follows:

```
if [ -z "$(acpi -i)" ]; then
  echo "battery not present"
else
  echo "battery present"
fi
```

Comment: `-z` checks if the length of STRING is zero.

Answer (score 2):

The python code below checks the output of `acpi -i`. if there is no output, "Where is my battery?" is printed, otherwise "OK, present". Of course you can put any command there, using either `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

get_batterystatus = subprocess.check_output(['acpi', '-i']).decode('utf-8').strip()

if get_batterystatus == "":
    print "Where is my battery?" 
else:
    print "OK, present"
```

Comment: This code is unnecessarily verbose (and slow). Why not `get_batterystatus = lambda: subprocess.check_output(['acpi', '-i'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).decode('utf-8').strip()`?

Comment: @phihag thanks for mentioning, I made some changes. That makes a difference, mainly in elegance; the timing is pretty much the same. Weird thing is that it is twice as fast in python2. left it in python2.

Comment: @KasiyA I am afraid I don't understand what you mean? Do you mean the () around the message? I changed it to python2 where in `print` no () is used.